# Surface groups as 3-manifold groups

Tags: low-dimensional-topology

From studiosus' answer to

[A 3-manifold with fundamental group isomorphic to a surface group.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734107/a-3-manifold-with-fundamental-group-isomorphic-to-a-surface-group)

a closed 3-manifold cannot have a fundamental group isomorphic to that of a closed surface of genus $\geq 2$.

What about genus 1? I wonder if there exist a closed 3-manifold with fundamental group isomorphic to the fundamental group of the 2-dimensional torus or the Klein bottle.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I found the answer here

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31904/closed-3-manifolds-with-free-abelian-fundamental-groups

Thanks again

Comment: Actually, the proof in my answer only uses the assumption that genus is $\ge 1$.